# Retrieve records from the database based on a possible id

Tags: f#

This code will retrieve all records from the database if the id is null or return records by the available id.  Is there a way to combine the query instead of having two separate queries?

```
// retrieve standard orders
let retrieveStdOrders id = 

    if id = null then
        query{
            for row in tool.db.Order_Order_StandardOrder do
            select {
                Id = row.Id;
                BusinessLocationId = row.BusinessLocationId;
                ProductOptionId = row.ProductOptionId;

            }
        }
    else
        query{
            for row in tool.db.Order_Order_StandardOrder do
            where(row.Id = id)
            select {
                Id = row.Id;
                BusinessLocationId = row.BusinessLocationId;
                ProductOptionId = row.ProductOptionId;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [F# query expressions and composability](http://fpish.net/blog/loic.denuziere/id/3508/2013924-f-query-expressions-and-composability).

Comment: If your function accepts an `id` value that could also be a non-value, you should rather use an option type: `let retrieveStdOrders id = match id with Some id -> (* do something with the id *) | None -> (* do something without an id *)` or even even shorter: `let retrieveStdOrders id = function Some id -> (* ... *) | None -> (* ... *)`.